# Add images to ListView corresponding to its content, obtained from JSON response

Tags: android, json

I am using JSON parser to parse JSON Response, where i am able to get item names in ListView but i am not able to get images corresponding to it. where image url's are present in JSON response. How can i parse response to get images corresponding to items. Following is the code, Any one who know how to do this kindly help me it would be very useful.

Note: images and items are NOT Fixed

```
public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

// url to make request
private static String url = "website/?JSON=get_recent_post";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";
private static final String TAG_CONTENT = "content";
private static final String TAG_AUTHOR = "author";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";



// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray posts = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        posts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
            String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
            String content = c.getString(TAG_CONTENT);

            // Phone number is agin  JSON Object
            JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(TAG_AUTHOR);
            String name = author.getString(TAG_NAME);


            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
            map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
            map.put( TAG_DATE, date);
            map.put( TAG_NAME, name);
            map.put( TAG_CONTENT, content);
            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);
        }   
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_DATE, TAG_NAME, TAG_CONTENT }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.email,R.id.mobile, R.id.content });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String date = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();
            String content = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_TITLE, title);
            in.putExtra(TAG_DATE, date);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_CONTENT, content);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });



}
```

}

JSONParser.java

public class JSONParser {

```
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

SingleMenuItem.java

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

// JSON node keys
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_CONTENT = "content";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get JSON values from previous intent
    String title = in.getStringExtra(TAG_TITLE);
    String date = in.getStringExtra(TAG_DATE);
    String name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
    String content = in.getStringExtra(TAG_CONTENT);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
    TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);
    TextView lblCont = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content_label);

    lblName.setText(title);
    lblCost.setText(date);
    lblDesc.setText(name);
    lblCont.setText(content);
}
```

}

Comment: learn how to create custom listview: http://www.thepcwizard.in/2012/09/android-creating-custom-listview-for.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to make your own adapter extending the [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) to have more freedom and flexibility...it's not too hard, you just have to bind the elements of the list row with the json data for the corresponding rows...on this binding you will also fetch the images, and assign to the [ImageViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html).

[SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) is meant for very simple stuff.